# image classifier 'Node' object has no attribute 'output_masks'

Tags: python

hiya so ive been doing this image classifier project for university and ive been having trouble with how to use the models and what codes to use and if im doing everything right ive been reading this but i still dont know why i keep getting errors https://keras.io/applications/#vgg16

I use these codes

```
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D
from keras.layers import Activation, Dropout, Flatten, Dense
from keras import backend as K
from PIL import ImageFile, Image
from tensorflow import keras

print(Image.__file__)
import numpy
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# dimensions of our images.
img_width, img_height = 200, 200

train_data_dir = r'C:\Users\Acer\imagerec\Brain\TRAIN'
validation_data_dir = r'C:\Users\Acer\imagerec\Brain\VAL'
nb_train_samples = 140
nb_validation_samples = 40
epochs = 20
batch_size = 5

if K.image_data_format() == 'channels_first':
    input_shape = (1, img_height, img_width)
else:
    input_shape = (img_height, img_width, 1)

from keras.applications.densenet import DenseNet121
from keras.models import Model
from keras.layers import Dense

MN = keras.applications.densenet.DenseNet121(include_top=False,
                                            weights='imagenet', input_tensor=None, input_shape=None,
                                            pooling='avg', classes=1000)
x = MN.output
x = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(x)
model = Model(MN.input, x)
model.summary()

model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',
              optimizer='rmsprop',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

# this is the augmentation configuration we will use for training
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
    rescale=1. / 255,
    shear_range=0.2,
    zoom_range=0.2,
    horizontal_flip=True)

# this is the augmentation configuration we will use for testing:
# only rescaling
test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1. / 255)

train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    train_data_dir,
    target_size=(img_width, img_height),
    batch_size=batch_size,
    class_mode='binary')

validation_generator = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    validation_data_dir,
    target_size=(img_width, img_height),
    batch_size=batch_size,
    class_mode='binary')

model.fit_generator(
    train_generator,
    steps_per_epoch=nb_train_samples // batch_size,
    epochs=epochs,
    validation_data=validation_generator,
    validation_steps=nb_validation_samples // batch_size)

from sklearn.metrics import classification_report
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
import seaborn as sns

test_steps_per_epoch = numpy.math.ceil(validation_generator.samples / validation_generator.batch_size)

predictions = model.predict_generator(validation_generator, steps=test_steps_per_epoch)
# Get most likely class
predicted_classes = numpy.argmax(predictions, axis=1)
true_classes = validation_generator.classes
class_labels = list(validation_generator.class_indices.keys())
report = classification_report(true_classes, predicted_classes, target_names=class_labels)
print(report)

cm=confusion_matrix(true_classes,predicted_classes)

sns.heatmap(cm, annot=True)

print(cm)

plt.show()
```

and got this error

```
2019-12-09 12:55:02.163825: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:142] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: AVX2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Acer/PycharmProjects/condas/VGG16.py", line 36, in <module>
    x = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(x)
  File "C:\Users\Acer\Anaconda3\envs\condas\lib\site-packages\keras\backend\tensorflow_backend.py", line 75, in symbolic_fn_wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Acer\Anaconda3\envs\condas\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\base_layer.py", line 475, in __call__
    previous_mask = _collect_previous_mask(inputs)
  File "C:\Users\Acer\Anaconda3\envs\condas\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\base_layer.py", line 1441, in _collect_previous_mask
    mask = node.output_masks[tensor_index]
AttributeError: 'Node' object has no attribute 'output_masks'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

im using python 3.6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an issue on GitHub regarding this subject [GitHub Keras 10907](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/10907)

In the posts there is something about tensorflow and keras relation:

> I had a similar issue, but with different architecture. As people
>   suggested, it's important not to mix keras with tensorflow.keras, so
>   try swapping
>
> ```
> import image from keras.models
> import Model from keras.layers 
> import Dense, GlobalAveragePooling2D
> from keras import backend as K
> ```
>
> to:
>
> ```py
> from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing import image 
> from tensorflow.keras.models import Model from tensorflow.keras.layers
> import Dense, GlobalAveragePooling2D 
> from tensorflow.keras import backend as K
> ```
>
> Also make sure, you don't use keras.something inside your code (not
>   only imports) as well, hope it helps : ) Also, I used Keras 2.2.4 with
>   tensorflow 1.10.0

Comment: hiya thanks for answering back ahhh hmm 
im tryna understand what to do 
ik this is wrong but what should i change again?
i got this

`from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing 
import image from
tensorflow.keras.models 
import Model from tensorflow.keras.layers
import Dense, GlobalAveragePooling2D from tensorflow.keras 
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D
from keras.layers import Activation, Dropout, Flatten, Dense
from keras import backend as K
from PIL import ImageFile, Image
from tensorflow import keras`

Comment: im using keras 2.3.1

Comment: Basically you have to use ```form tensorflow.keras import ...``` for tensorflow related codes, and ```from keras import ... ``` for pure keras codes. Your issue related with this wrong addressing. First, you need to map what you need and which keras you're gonna get this need either ```tensorflow.keras``` or directly from pure ```keras```.

Comment: hiya so whenever i do that this error comes up `NameError: name 'keras' is not defined`

Comment: Try to install keras using pip ```pip install Keras``` or ```pip3 install Keras```. Seems that you don't have keras pure package or installed wrong.